# Stata variable definition with backquote

Tags: stata, ado, backquote

I have obtained a copy of Stata ado file written by another researcher. The first few lines are as follows:

```
   program define threshold, eclass
   set more off
   gen m=`1'
   sort mvar
   gen lagm=L.m
   gen deltam=D.m
   ...
```

What does the line **gen m=`1'** do?
I could not find convincing answer. So any clarification is appreciated!

Comment: It is the first argument supplied to the program. `threshold frog` would mean that the variable name `frog` is the first argument. If you received a program without a help file, expect to do most of the work. All this is documented prominently. e.g. http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u18.pdf 18.4

Answer (score 0):

See the official documentation, e.g. Section 18.4 in http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u18.pdf. Or just play around:

```
capture program drop mytest
program define mytest
display `"`0'"'
display `"`1'"'
display `"`2'"'
end

mytest some arbitrary syntax here
```

Comment: It can be useful to actually write the description here. Links can break, etc. The way this answer is currently written doesn't answer the question.